# Trigger error: Record "new" is not assigned yet

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert

I have the following code in postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_category() RETURNS trigger AS $newProduct$
BEGIN
    UPDATE category SET product_count = product_count + 1 WHERE cat_id = NEW.cat_id;
    INSERT INTO notification (content, type, p_id) VALUES('new product', 1, NEW.p_id);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$newProduct$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_cat AFTER INSERT ON product
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_category();
```

And after inserting a record into product I get the error:

```
[2017-03-20 16:05:05] [55000] ERROR: record "new" is not assigned yet
[2017-03-20 16:05:05] Detail: The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
[2017-03-20 16:05:05] Where: SQL statement "UPDATE category SET product_count = product_count + 1 WHERE cat_id = NEW.cat_id"
[2017-03-20 16:05:05] PL/pgSQL function update_category() line 3 at SQL statement
```

I've looked around for a solution, but I only find cases where the error is because

```
FOR EACH STATEMENT
```

is being used instead of

```
FOR EACH ROW
```

Seeing as I'm simply executing the procedure once, the solution doesn't apply in my case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "the solution doesn't apply in my case" - why not? It doesn't matter how many rows you affect with a STATEMENT trigger, you still don't have the NEW variable do you?

Comment: @RichardHuxton you were right! Changing it to FOR EACH ROW does work, I assumed that it meant 'call the procedure once for each row in product'

Answer (score 8):

The solution was indeed to add FOR EACH ROW:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_cat AFTER INSERT ON product
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_category();
```

I assumed FOR EACH ROW meant calling the procedure once for each row in product, not for each row inserted.